# How to remove all '\' characters from a string in java

Tags: java, string, replaceall

In my code I have a string, from which I need to remove all the "\" (Backslash) from. I'm trying to use `String.replaceAll` but it's throwing the Exception: "String literal is not properly closed by a double quote."

```
String links = new String(image[0]);
String changed = links.replaceAll("\", "");
```

" input - Image[0] " has links with a bunch of "\ / \ /" going on inside them I tried to post one but Stack Overflow edited the link to not have the "\"

Comment: You want to remove ```"\"``` but the link contains only ```"/"```?

Comment: @Andrew Wayne, could you add what is the value for image[0] here, that is input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the regular expression with four backward slash "\\\\" in the above program. This will resolve the exception. The regular expression string will convert the four backward slash to 2 backward slash. The two backward slash “\\” is identified as single slash in regular expression matching.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String links = new String("data \\");
        String changed = links.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
        System.out.println(changed);
    }
}
```